# Where does Leia stand in the resistance command structure?

Tags: star-wars

Leia seems to have the rank "General" in the resistance, where does this sit in the command structure?

My (limited) understanding of real world militaries is that General in the Army is equivalent of Admiral in the navy, does this put Leia on equal footing with Akbar and the other admirals?

Comment: In the real world, there are different grades of admiral and general. A Rear Admiral is far below an Admiral of the Fleet. So we'd need to know a lot more about the Resistance's rank structure, and Leia's and Ackbar's full ranks, in order to answer the question.

Comment: @MikeScott I take it we don't have that info?

Comment: She's in charge. Kinda.

Comment: Don't forget Han and Lando were both generals in RotJ.

Comment: @MikeScott. I think you're overthinking it. Formal structures aren't democratic.

Comment: @Valorum Armed forces aren't democratic either. Even the French Revolutionary Navy had different flag ranks (although they threw the Navy into disarray by dismissing or executing all the experienced officers who had previously held those ranks).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In The Force Awakens Leia appears to be in semi-overall charge of the Resistance, or at the very least *deferred to* on almost all major decisions.

> *History had accorded the woman many names and titles, from princess of Alderaan to **leader of the Resistance**, but to Han she was simply Leia. His wife.*
>
> <sup><sub>[The Force Awakens: Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_A_Junior_Novel)</sub></sup>

That being said, the Resistance, like the Rebellion before it, appears to have quite a loose leadership structure based on ***mutual decision-making amongst multiple leaders***. It's unlikely that Leia would override Ackbar on matters of starship war strategy, for example.

> *When she had proposed the idea, the shock of objection on the part of her fellow Resistance leaders could have been heard halfway across the galaxy. Reluctantly, she had conceded to reason. Someone would go in her stead.*
>
> <sup><sub>[The Force Awakens: Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel))</sub></sup>

And

> *There had been some further argument, especially from other leaders who had remained convinced that the pilot chosen to follow up on the slender lead was too young for such a crucial task. **In the end, harmony had triumphed.**          Once again she caught her reflection in the metal. **It had been some time since she had not prevailed in the course of such discussions.***
>
> *A thin, knowing smile gleamed back at her. No doubt her authority in such matters derived from her shy, retiring nature.*
>
> <sup><sub>[The Force Awakens: Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel))</sub></sup>